# Good algorithms for high dimension and low sample size data

Tags: algorithm

I am dealing with some high dimension data with small sample size. I have tried some algorithms such as linear regression, SVM, PLSR etal. But they showed bad performance. So are there some good algorithms for low sample size?

Comment: random forest??

Comment: You may have much better luck getting this answered in Stack Overflow's sister site [Crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).